# React - dangerouslySetInnerHTML and content with broken tags

Tags: reactjs

I am using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute to display HTML content from the backend. The assumption is that the HTML content is *not* guaranteed to be valid. It could have unclosed or unmatched tags.

React raises an `Uncaught Invariant Violation` when the content has unclosed and unmatched tags. My guess is that the browser tried fixing the tags. Doing so mutated the DOM which raised the error.

Is there a way to circumvent this or set the inner HTML of the div?